# Use multiple words on each line of text file as input to batch script

Tags: batch-file

The text file (input.txt) I am trying to use as input looks like this:

```
v0_6_20161028S Project_Name1
v0_6_20162028S Project_Name2
v0_6_20163028S Project_Name3
```

I want to use the first part of each line (v0_6_20...) for a query and the second part of each line (Project_Name...) to create a directory. How can I loop through each line of this text file and use both elements for commands?

```
FOR /F %%i in (PVCS_VersionLabels.txt) DO (
   queryCommand lineWord1
   mkdir lineWord2
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
FOR /F "tokens=1*" %%i in (PVCS_VersionLabels.txt) DO (
   queryCommand %%i
   mkdir %%j
)
```

see `for /?` from the prompt for documentation. I'd create the directory first.

Comment: Better would be `mkdir "%%~j"` in case of file `PVCS_VersionLabels.txt` contains ever a directory name with a space or other character with special meaning outside a double quoted argument string.